# How to redirect UPD packages targeted for other host to localhost

Tags: routing, nftables

I want to sniff UDP packages targeted at port 4500 flowing from machine A -> B with a physical TAP device and receive the sniffed packages on machine C on a local port (see image).
[image]

About the TAP Device: This is a physical device which is placed in between A and B. The traffic between A and B is not modified at all but the packages are also sent to the TAP output interface to machine C (packages received on C are still addressed to B because the TAP is not doing modifications)

**My goal** is to receive all data which are targeted at port 4500 on machine C in client programs like `netcat`.

**The problem** obviously is, that packages received at the NIC of C are not targeted for C and therefore the packages are dropped before coming anywhere close to the applications layers of the OSi model.

What I've already tried is using `nftables` to redirect packages, but somehow my netcat still doesn't get messages. Can someone help me out what I'm doing wrong or suggest what the best way is to solve this?

```bash
nft 'add chain nat udpredirect { type nat hook prerouting priority -101 ; policy accept ; }'
nft 'add rule ip nat PREROUTING udp dport 4500 redirect'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is here: https://serverfault.com/a/1125704/570881

The  netdev family must be used to modify packages already early enough before the kernel drops them.