# Packets dropped when the target addresses (mac and ip) are changed to own hosts interface

Tags: networking, nftables

My host acts as a router and has two network interfaces `enp1s0` (1 host connected with ip `192.168.10.20`) and `enp2s0`. `enp1s0` is used to receive UDP packages and `enp2s0` usually has the listening hosts connected.

When I activate the `nftables` logging with:

```
table ip filter {
        chain logging {
                type filter hook prerouting priority filter; policy accept;
                ip saddr 192.168.10.20 log prefix "ip-filter1-"
        }
}
```

I see all packets from `192.168.10.20` being logged and I also see in the log, what the actual target of the packages are (because my host is just the router and passes the packages through).

Nevertheless, when I try to do some very low level redirecting in the `netdev` family, the logs are no longer printed (I assume that the packets are dropped, aren't they?)

```
table netdev filter { # handle 3
        chain mod { # handle 15
                type filter hook ingress device "enp1s0" priority -500; policy accept;
                ether daddr set c4:00:ad:99:67:c7 ip daddr set 192.168.10.120 # handle 16
        }
}
```

This is my `ip a`

```
...
2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c4:00:ad:99:67:c7 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.10.120/24 brd 192.168.10.255 scope global noprefixroute enp1s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::c600:adff:fe99:67c7/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c4:00:ad:99:67:c8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.20.75.50/24 brd 10.20.75.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp2s0
       valid_lft 682026sec preferred_lft 682026sec
    inet6 fe80::c600:adff:fe99:67c8/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

`ip route` gives me:

```
default via 10.20.75.254 dev enp2s0 proto dhcp metric 101
10.20.75.0/24 dev enp2s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.20.75.50 metric 101
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp1s0 scope link metric 1000
192.168.10.0/24 dev enp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.10.120 metric 100
```

Why is it, that packets are no longer logged after I do a rewrite of the mac address and the ip address to the values of the local NIC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using the `netdev` family with `nftables`:

This is how packages on the NIC are redirected to a local interface:

```
table netdev filter {
        chain redir {
                type filter hook ingress device "enp1s0" priority filter; policy accept;
                ether daddr set c4:00:ad:99:67:c7 ip daddr set 192.168.10.120 udp dport set 4500 meta pkttype set host
        }
}
```

The promiscuous mode must be turned on in order that the NIC forwards packages not intended for it:

```
ip link set enp1s0 promisc on
```